# AddJoin_management crashes ArcMap

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-desktop, attribute-joins, arcgis-10.2

I am going to be using an AddJoin_management command in a python script at the end of several loops. To test, I used the AddJoin tool and use the below command in the Python window and made the parameters identical to what the code is(the parameters are correct for what I want to accomplish). When I run the AddJoin it crunches numbers for a while and then the whole program crashes and asks if I would like to send an error report.

```
arcpy.AddJoin_management("SignsToFinish", "SignID", "NewSigns", "sid", "KEEP_ALL")
```

That is the statement that is being used in both the script and in the AddJoin tool.

Why does this cause ArcMap to crash? Any ideas?

Comment: What version of ArcGIS? Have you checked to see if you're running out of memory?

Comment: Figured it out. ArcMap 10.2 but the problem was inconsistent field types.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that the two reference fields had the same information but were of different field types. It was throwing the error because comparing short and text doesn't work.